# Prevent an element hidden when it clicked

Tags: javascript, css

I made an element with `visibility: hidden`, it turn out `visibility: visible` when its `:hover`. It works perfectly on desktop view, but on mobile web it will dissappear when the element being clicked. How can I resolve this? Only set to hidden/dissapear when we click outside the element or the close button.

Comment: Would [the `:focus-within` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) work?

Comment: create a snippet what you tried?

Comment: Please take the tour first. Then read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for debugging details. Pictures with code-lines are inacceptable!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:hover` doesn't fire in mobiles, since mobiles are only click. *(You got nothing to hover with!)*

Luckily, if you use `:active` selector in combination with `:hover` you can achieve this as long as the `:active` is after `:hover`.

```
.element:hover, .element:active{
   visibility: visible;
 }
```